# Reading the value of a custom control property through a Control object

Tags: c#, custom-controls

I have 3 custom controls, all of them have a property with a name "MyCustomProperty", let's say i need to use

```
foreach (control c in this.controls)
```

how can i reach MyCustomProperty through the object c ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Step 1. Give your controls a common interface that exposes the property.

```
interface IPropertyHolder
{
    string MyCustomProperty { get; }
}

class MyCustomControl1 : TextBox, IPropertyHolder
{
    public string MyCustomProperty { get; set; }
}

class MyCustomControl2 : Form, IPropertyHolder
{
    public string MyCustomProperty { get; set; }
}

class MyCustomControl3 : Control, IPropertyHolder
{
    public string MyCustomProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Step 2. Either cast it:

```
foreach (var c in this.controls)
{
    var custom = c as IPropertyHolder;
    if (custom != null)
    {
        var temp = c.MyCustomProperty;
    }
}
```

Or only include controls that have the interface:

```
foreach (var c in this.controls.OfType<IPropertyHolder>())
{
    var temp = c.MyCustomProperty;
}
```

Comment: It's likely that instead of deriving from `Control` the OP will want to derive from different types of controls (e.g. `TextBox`, `Label`, etc).  This answer will work for that, just replace `Control` with whichever control you intend to use.

Comment: "Interface" saved my life :) THANKS

Answer (score 1):

You could use reflection to identify controls with your property, then use a `dynamic` to access the property:

```
using System.Reflection;

if (c.GetType().GetProperty("MyCustomProperty") != null)
{
  string something = ((dynamic)c).MyCustomProperty; //Assuming your property is a string
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Is there another way to get the value of the property? the demonstrated one requires me to add Microsoft.CSharp and switch to a higher .net framework, which i cannot do for some reasons

Answer (score 0):

Test that the control is of the proper type, then cast it by giving it a name (`myC` here):

```
if (c is MyCustomControl myC)
{
  var something = myC.MyCustomProperty;
}
```

The following is the equivalent, but could be easier to understand:

```
if (c is MyCustomControl)
{
  var myC = (MyCustomControl)c;
  var something = myC.MyCustomProperty;
}
```

Comment: I have 3 different custom controls (of different types, but they all share the same property, is there anything like c.properties("MyCustomProperty").value?

Comment: @HayanAlMamoun See my new answer.